Old animated film about an evil villain swapping traits between animals using a weird machines with 2 crystal capsules
I saw this movie many years ago, all I can remember is that it was an animated movie featuring anthropomorphic animals, they were in some sort of journey to an island while riding on a boat and singing a song, the evil character was on this island using a two crystal capsules machine to swap traits between animals, I vividly remember a exposition scene where they swapped traits between a dog and a pig, making the dog fat like a pig and the pig thin and cheerful like a dog, I saw this movie when I was living in Venezuela so IDK if the movie originated from Latin America, I don't think that's the case since I remember the animation quality being too high for a movie made in the region at the time, I've spent years looking for this movie and I can't never find it

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about approximately what year you watched this?

Was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

between 1993 and 2003 I saw it on TV on a local network channel, I don't recall much besides what's on the description above, I think I probably watched like 20 minutes of the movie and then somebody changed the TV's channel

to add to that, in this island there was all kind of mixed animals, all sort of animals that looked like the product of this evil villain and his trait swapping machine

@LogicDictates it was hand-drawn

I guess I'm never finding this movie, lmao
